# Discord.py TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'search'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.guild.id == 464298877823221761:
            if message.content.find("!yt") != -1:
                query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': message})
                htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
                search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(.{11})',htm_content.read().decode())
                await message.channel.send('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
                await self.bot.process_commands
```

Having some trouble here, I tried reading the documentation but nothing, any help is much appreciated, thanks

Example of what is should work like:
`!yt Never gonna give you up`

Bot: `https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ`

Here is the entire code cog: https://hastebin.com/icaturepup.py

I updated the question, and with this version, I am able to get a search youtube but it searches the entire string, I need to only search the string after `!yt` if anyone here knows how that is possible please let me know, again all help is apprecaited

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#event-reference

it's `async def on_message(self, message)`. There is no `ctx`

Comment: I am not using a command for a purpose, I am asking if there is a way to do this with `on_message`

Comment: Here you see a method decorated by `@commands.Cog.listener()` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#quick-example
Again: There is no `ctx` in the method parameters.

Comment: Thanks, for the help

Answer (score 2):

the `on_message` event only takes 1 parameter, which is the message object itself.
You want to do

```
async def on_message(self, ctx, message):
```

Then instead of taking the search parameter (which from what I can tell, was supposed to be the entire message content.) You can do this using the `.content` attribute to the message object.

so then you can get your query string by doing this:

```
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': message.content})
```

Comment: that won't work since that will bring up the error: `TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'`    I appreciate the assistance

Comment: Here is my entire cog: https://hastebin.com/emasojutec.py

Comment: The code you provided is faulty. Please see my comments under OPs question and edit your answer.